# Kafka client connection issue for spring boot 3.1.X and above

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

i recently upgraded one of my spring boot service to 3.1.x after the upgrade im getting issues with kafka. Its seems like its not able to connect and keep giving me the below log.

```
2024-01-03T06:18:46.313456838Z 2024-01-03T06:18:46.313Z WARN 1 --- [servicerequestorms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG-1, groupId=Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
Wed, Jan 3 2024 11:48:47 am
2024-01-03T06:18:47.403Z INFO 1 --- [servicerequestorms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG-1, groupId=Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG] Node -1 disconnected. 2024-01-03T06:18:47.403489607Z 2024-01-03T06:18:47.403Z WARN 1 --- [servicerequestorms] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG-1, groupId=Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

But when i switch back to spring boot 3.0.x it works fine. Im using
`spring-kafka 3.1.1` in my project. I also tried with the latest spring boot 3.2.1 but its giving the same issue, the issue only happening with spring boot version 3.1.x and above.

Here is my spring kafka properties

```
kafka:
  consumer:
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonDeserializer
    group-id: Dev_Phoenix_ServiceRequestor_CG
  producer:
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
  properties:
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: https
    sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
    bootstrap.servers: xyz.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
    sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='username' password='password';
    security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    schema.registry.url: https://xyz.westus2.azure.confluent.cloud  
    basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
    schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info: M2T3WWJYIPFI5NBO:qSZikyV70b1h7tEHtmenmLTje7+aeUi6h+ZwRZ6scwLYUzzo9EhI70bk8OuWEH4Y
    #specific.avro.reader: true
    json.value.type: com.xxx.phoenix.events.DomainEvent
```

Here is the kafkaAdmin config

```
@Configuration
public class DomainEventsKafkaTopicConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String phoenixClusterJAASConfig;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism:PLAIN}")
    private String phoenixClusterSASLMechanism;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol:SASL_SSL}")
    private String phoenixClusterSecurityProtocol;
    @Value("${phoenix.domain.event.topic.name}")
    private String domainEventTopic;
    @Value("${phoenix.domain.event.topic.partitions:3}")
    private int domainEventTopicPartitions;
    @Value("${phoenix.domain.event.topic.replicationFactor:3}")
    private int domainEventTopicReplicationFactor;

    public DomainEventsKafkaTopicConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap();
        configs.put("bootstrap.servers", this.bootstrapAddress);
        configs.put("security.protocol", this.phoenixClusterSecurityProtocol);
        configs.put("sasl.mechanism", this.phoenixClusterSASLMechanism);
        configs.put("sasl.jaas.config", this.phoenixClusterJAASConfig);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic(this.domainEventTopic, this.domainEventTopicPartitions, (short)this.domainEventTopicReplicationFactor);
    }
}
```

Im stuck and not able to upgrade the spring boot version, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It supposed to be like this:

```
 spring:
   kafka:
     bootstrap-servers: xyz.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
```

Starting with Spring Boot `3.1.0`, there is a `ConnectionDetails` abstraction now and that `bootstrap.servers` Kafka property is out of use from now on:

```
private void applyKafkaConnectionDetailsForConsumer(Map<String, Object> properties,
        KafkaConnectionDetails connectionDetails) {
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, connectionDetails.getConsumerBootstrapServers());
    if (!(connectionDetails instanceof PropertiesKafkaConnectionDetails)) {
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "PLAINTEXT");
    }
}
```

Comment: Im using kafkaAdmin so spring.kafka.properties isnt a problem. I updated the question, i did get how to use the applyKafkaConnectionDetailsForConsumer.

Comment: Why would one crate his/her/their own `KafkaAdmin`, if Spring Boot auto-configure that for us? What is your question though fro now on?

Comment: Its an existing code that im working on, i just upgraded the spring boot version from 3.0.12 to 3.2.1 and suddenly kafka bootstrap server by default settings to localhost instead of the remote host.

Comment: OK. I've just explained you in the answer that you cannot use `spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers` to auto-configure those beans for Spring Kafka.

Comment: But i have tried with spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers it also didn't worked.

Comment: Sounds like time for your to share with us a simple project where we can reproduce the problem and explain in its README what exactly you'd like to achieve. Doesn't look like `KafkaAdmin` has some relevance to the question though.

Comment: spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers did the trick, i was using a dot instead of the dash.